# Calculate how many products will fit in the carton | Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

at the beginning I inform you that I didn't find an answer on stackoverflow for this topic.

I am looking for a function in Google sheet that would be able to automatically calculate for me how many packages of matches will fit in a collective carton

I currently have this data:

product dimensions

```
| product    | length | width | height
| -----------|----------------|-------
| product 1  | 736    | 82    | 44
```

the dimensions of the collective carton

```
| carton      | length | width | height
| ------------|----------------|-------
| Big Shelves | 1050   | 390   | 600
| Mezzanine   | 600    | 270   | 260
```

I tried converting by cubic meters but it doesn't count correctly for example it calculates as follows

'Product 1' in 'Big Shelves' fits 93 pcs. And I am aware that there will be less products
'Product 1' in 'Mezzanine' fits 16 pcs. Where it is not possible because the product is longer than the longest side of the collective carton

I created a spreadsheet in google for easier viewing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRaMFl3j-tUaKWljR9ntUpSV7jh5g1-FSw4FGGeT9d8/edit?usp=sharing

| Name product | Battery |  | Kg | length | width | height | Vol, m3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 0,25 | 0.736 | 0.082 | 0.044 | 0.002655488 |
| Pallet capacity |  | KG |  | Length | Width | Height | Vol, m3 |
| Mezzanine - | 16 | 4 | Big Shelves | 1.05 | 0.39 | 0.6 | 0.2457 |
| Big Shelves | 93 | 23.25 | Mezzanine | 0.6 | 0.27 | 0.26 | 0.04212 |

I am waiting for suggestions and answers.

Comment: Please, no links to external sites, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=If%20it%20is%20possible%20to%20create%20a%20live%20example%20of%20the%20problem%20that%20you%20can%20link%20to%20(for%20example%2C%20on%20http%3A//sqlfiddle.com/%20or%20http%3A//jsbin.com/)%20then%20do%20so%E2%80%94but%20also%20copy%20the%20code%20into%20the%20question%20itself.%20Not%20everyone%20can%20access%20external%20sites%2C%20and%20the%20links%20may%20break%20over%20time.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask, see: [How to calculate how much items fit inside a box?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415223/how-to-calculate-how-much-items-fit-inside-a-box), and because this is a match problem, not a google-sheets problem.

Comment: I posted a question earlier about another thing and someone downgraded my show reserch due to the lack of a link, besides, I don't know if I can paste any code there since I use Google sheet, http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: I added the data from the google-sheet to your question .

Comment: This sounds like a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). In the general case, it is not as easy to solve as one would naïvely assume. See [next-fit bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-fit_bin_packing) for one possible approach.

Comment: thank you very much for your help thanks to this I found the answer and created a forum that works

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, I'm pasting the formula for others, maybe it will help someone like me

the first formula that calculates the longest side

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/SMALL(G3:I3,2)))
```

and the second formula that calculates the shortest side

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G3:I3;2)/MAX(G6:I6)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))
```

**Note to subsequent readers:**

The above is not an optimal strategy because it fixes the orientation of items in the container by a rigid rule and does not allow for other orientations. In the general case, it will not find the true number of items that will fit in a container. Here is a simple example of why that matters:

[image: Packing strategy]

See [packing_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), [rectangle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing) and [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) for more information.

The following solution attempt will give the correct number of boxes in some scenarios, but will give an incorrect result in others:

first formula

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/SMALL(G3:I3,2)))+((MAX(G6:I6)-ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))/SMALL(G3:I3,2)
```

second formula

```
=((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN((SMALL(G6:I6;2)-MAX(G3:I3))/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))
```

third formula that combines the above formulas, choosing the larger of their results:

```
=IF((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+((MAX(G6:I6)-ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))/SMALL(G3:I3;2)>((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN((SMALL(G6:I6;2)-MAX(G3:I3))/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3));(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+((MAX(G6:I6)-ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))/SMALL(G3:I3;2);((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN((SMALL(G6:I6;2)-MAX(G3:I3))/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))
```

**Note:** the second and third formulas above will happily pack six 1x1x1 cubes in a 2x2x1 box, which is incorrect. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:10_kvadratoj_en_kvadrato.svg) is an illustration why finding the *optimal* packing strategy is such a hard problem:

[image: Square packing with rotation]

The third formula can be rewritten as a lambda to make it a tad easier to follow (but it will still give incorrect results):

```
=lambda(
  itemX, itemY, itemZ,
  boxX, boxY, boxZ,
  lambda(
    numFitXX, numFitYY, numFitZZ,
    numFitXY, numFitYX, numFitZY,
    max(
      numFitXX * numFitYY * numFitZZ + (boxX - itemX * numFitXX) / itemY,
      numFitXY * numFitYX * numFitZY + numFitXX * rounddown((boxY - itemX) / itemY)
    )
  )(
    rounddown(boxX / itemX), rounddown(boxY / itemY), rounddown(boxZ / itemZ),
    rounddown(boxX / itemY), rounddown(boxY / itemX), rounddown(boxZ / itemY)
  )
)(
  max(G3: I3), small(G3: I3, 2), min(G3: I3),
  max(G6: I6), small(G6: I6, 2), min(G6: I6)
)
```

Sorry, my fault, I pasted the wrong code :) it is corrected

The third code that selects a larger quantity

```
=IF((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)-(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3))>((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)-(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3));(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)-(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3));((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)-(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))
```

second code

```
=((ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)-(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))
```

first code

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/MIN(G3:I3)))*(ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/SMALL(G3:I3;2)))+ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)-(ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX(G3:I3))*MAX(G3:I3)))*ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6;2)/MAX(G3:I3))
```

and yes, you are right, this is a very big problem but for me this option is sufficient, it is possible that someone will be able to: D create a formula that will calculate it

Now this code should work properly

```html
=IF((ROUNDDOWN(IF(MOD(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3)))*IF(MOD(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3)))*   IF(MOD(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))))>ROUNDDOWN(IF(MOD(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))*IF(MOD(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3)))*IF(MOD(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))),ROUNDDOWN(IF(MOD(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/MAX($G$3:$I$3)))*IF(MOD(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MIN($G$3:$I$3)))*   IF(MOD(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))),ROUNDDOWN(IF(MOD(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MAX(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))*IF(MOD(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),1)=0.333333333333334,SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3),ROUNDDOWN(SMALL(G6:I6,2)/MAX($G$3:$I$3)))*IF(MOD(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),1)=0.333333333333334,MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2),ROUNDDOWN(MIN(G6:I6)/SMALL($G$3:$I$3,2)))))
```

Comment: I added a solution to the above problem

Comment: The second and third formulas will happily pack six 1x1x1 cubes in a 2x2x1 box, which is incorrect. There is no simple formula to find the _optimal_ solution in the general case. Edited the answer to add a couple of links and illustration why this is a hard problem.

Comment: I made a correction, I did not copy this function

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AzjU.png <--- for me the formula shows the correct result (approximate) there is no error you write about, go to the google link and there you can check if it works correctly

Comment: That looks quite promising! Found an issue though. Two hundred 3x1x1 items should fit in a 6x10x10 container, but the formula only packs 183. See the [test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRaMFl3j-tUaKWljR9ntUpSV7jh5g1-FSw4FGGeT9d8/edit#gid=1017186103) tab.

Comment: please check the code now and if it shows wrong point me the error

Comment: I think your most recent formula gets even better results than the previous one. There are issues though: _thirteen_ 7x1x1 items should fit in a 10x10x1 box, but the formula only packs _ten_ items there. Also, adding a third dimension is problematic. _Nine_ 1x1x2 items should fit in a 3x3x2 box, but the formula only packs _six_. See the [test2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRaMFl3j-tUaKWljR9ntUpSV7jh5g1-FSw4FGGeT9d8/edit#gid=1146609542) and [test3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRaMFl3j-tUaKWljR9ntUpSV7jh5g1-FSw4FGGeT9d8/edit#gid=1640327518) tabs.